# Magento 2 : When running integration tests, how can I override some of the dependencies that are injected?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection, object-manager, phpunit, integration-test

I am running an integration test for Magento 2, but I am at a certain point that my integration test needs a different dependency than my production code. Without going too much into detail as to why, I noticed that Magento does the same thing in `dev/tests/integration/etc/di/preferences/ce.php`.

In this file, Magento maps certain dependencies to framework classes, for example:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http::class => \Magento\TestFramework\Request::class
```

No I thought this would be the right place for my di override, so I added a file to this folder with my own dependency override:

`dev/tests/integration/etc/di/preferences/custom.php`:

```
return [
    \Vendor\Module\Api\StrategyPoolInterface::class => \Vendor\Module\Test\Integration\Di\StrategyPool::class
];
```

However, this does not seem to work. My integration test still uses the original class instead of the override set in my `custom.php` file. The file does get picked up, I already checked that, and my dependency is added to the list (you can see this in `dev/tests/integration/framework/Magento/TestFramework/ObjectManagerFactory.php::_loadPrimaryConfig()`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

**Edit:**

When I try the following directly in my integration test, it works as expected:

```
$this->om = Bootstrap::getObjectManager();
$this->om->configure([
    'preferences' => [
        \Vendor\Module\Api\StrategyPoolInterface::class => \Vendor\Module\Test\Integration\Di\StrategyPool::class
    ]
]);
```

So why doesn't it work when I put it in a separate file?

Comment: Where do you include `custom.php`? Besides that, I'd consider the working solution from your edit the correct one. Keep the setup close to the tests themselves. If it gets complex and you need to reuse it across several tests, you can still extract it to a script or class inside your test suite

Comment: In `dev/tests/integration/etc/di/preferences`. And it gets picked up. Although I also agree with your remark to keep the setup as close to the test as possible.